# Java & Mockito - passing an argument to a method AND capturing the result

Tags: java, hibernate, mockito

I'm trying to fix some existing junit/mockito tests that I've had to alter due to a re-write to use Dao's.

So I have this argument captor :-

```
ArgumentCaptor<CustomerDao> customerDaoCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(CustomerDao.class);
```

and I've used this approach before to get the (customer) object so that I can perform more tests on it. I would usually use it like this :-

```
verify(customerDao, times(1)).saveOrUpdate(customerDaoCaptor.capture());
```

so that I can then run tests like :-

```
Customer customerActual = (Customer) customerDaoCaptor.getAllValues().get(0);
assertEquals("PRE", customerActual.getExistingCustomer());
```

However in this instance I'm not calling the saveOrUpdate method (that the captor is bound to), but another Dao method that takes a unique key as a parameter that ultimately updates the customer record by using sql - ie it doesnt use the parent object's (Hibernate) saveOrUpdate method.

I know that I can test that its called, eg :-

```
inOrder.verify(customerDao, times(1)).updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber(CUSTOMER_NUMBER);
```

so I'm trying to somehow assign/bind the captor to the 'updateRegisterStatus....' method, but I cant seem to find a way to do it, mainly because that method must take a string param, customer_number.

So in essence I'm trying to do this :-

```
inOrder.verify(customerDao, times(1)).updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber(CUSTOMER_NUMBER).customerDaoCaptor.capture()
```

which obviously doesn't work...

As a lot of googling hasn't helped me, I'm guessing that I'm doing it completely wrong.

Update - @SpaceTrucker

I've tried the following code as you suggested :-

```
CapturingMatcher<String> capturingMatcher = new CapturingMatcher<String>();
    verify(customerDao, times(1)).updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber(
        argThat(
            org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf(capturingMatcher, org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue())
        )
    );
    List<String> values = capturingMatcher.getAllValues();
```

based on my Dao implementation :-

```
public void updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber(String customerNumber)
```

and it does pass the test successfully, in that it doesn't fail, but it doesnt do everything what I need it to. The ideal goal here is to somehow get an object representing the updated customer object - eg :-

```
Customer customerActual = (Customer) values.get(0);
assertEquals("value", customerActual.getExistingCustomer());
```

However the values object is empty and on debugging the test I can confirm that the method in question is being called.

Apologies in advance if there's something trivial that I've missed here, and once again, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Shouldn't the captor be defined like `ArgumentCaptor<Customer> customerCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Customer.class);`? This would save you the casting when getting captured values.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to more difficult than first thought about. See below for more details on this.

The `Matcher` instance Mockito does need to see has to implement the `CapturesArguments` interface. So the solution is to implement an `AndMatcher` that will delegate to its child matchers and implements `CapturesArguments`. It will delegate to all child matchers that also implement `CapturesArguments` when `CapturesArguments.captureFrom(Object)`. Please note that `CapturesArguments` is a Mockito internal interface.

---

**The following solution does not work**,
because the `Matcher` instance Mockito sees, doesn't implement the `CapturesArguments` interface and therefore won't delegate the argument capturing to the `CapturingMatcher`.

The `ArgumentCaptor` uses a [`CapturingMatcher`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/internal/matchers/CapturingMatcher.html) internally. So you could use `Mockito.argThat` with a combined matcher that will consist of a `CapturingMatcher` and any other matcher you like.

For example given the interface

```
public interface ProductService {
    List<Product> getProductsForCategory(Category category);
}
```

then we can do the following:

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

// ...    

CapturingMatcher<Category> capturingMatcher = new CapturingMatcher<Category>();
Mockito.verify(productService).getProductsForCategory(Mockito.argThat(Matchers.allOf(capturingMatcher, Matchers.notNullValue())));
List<Category> values = capturingMatcher.getAllValues();
```

You could also implement your own `ArgumentCaptor` with a `capture` method that will take an additional matcher instance.

Comment: Hi SpaceTrucker, 

Thanks for your help, but dispite researching your comment, I'm still lost with this one. Could you please be a little more specific, ideally with code examples if at all possible - I'm very new to Mockito...
Thanks again,
Ian

Comment: @IanGallimore When you use `ArgumentCaptor` the type argument of it should always be the type of the argument that is being capture and not the type of the object where a method is called on and the captor is used on one of the methods arguments.

Comment: I've updated my original post if you have the time and patience ?

Comment: Beware that `CapturingMatcher` is part of an `org.mockito.internal` package and is liable to change without notice. Switching to `AdditionalMatchers.and(eq(CUSTOMER_NUMBER), captor.capture())` would be preferable, if it works.

Comment: @JeffBowman unfortunately `AdditionalMatchers` won't help here because of the same reason my first proposed solution doesn't work. See my updated answers for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'm getting the following points from it:

1. You have a mock of a `CustomerDao`.
2. Your test (indirectly) calls the `updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber()` method of this mock, passing a `String` identifier to it.
3. `updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber()` does something internally to a `Customer` object.
4. You want to test things about the `Customer` object in question.

If these are correct, then you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how mocks work. That internal code that does something to a `Customer` object? In this test, that code doesn't exist. It's never called. The mock version of `CustomerDao` responds to your `updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber()` call by simply returning what your test setup code told it to, whether that's `null`, a carefully crafted sample object, or another mock. It never invokes the actual `CustomerDao` code because the whole point of a mock is to make your test not be dependent on that code, so that bugs in that code don't cascade test failures throughout the dependency tree.

To test the internal behavior of `CustomerDao.updateRegisterStatusToCurrentByCustomerNumber()`, you will need to create separate tests that directly call `CustomerDao` methods on a *non-mock* `CustomerDao`, with everything *else* being mocks.